# Multiple Threads executing same Method (Non Synchronized) behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronization, executorservice

I called a method that adds an item to a list from multiple threads, the method is not synchronized

```
static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

static void addItem(int itemNo){
    
    list.add("item "+itemNo);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        int itemNo = i;
        Runnable task = () -> addItem(itemNo);
        executor.execute(task);
    }
    
    executor.shutdown();
    
    
    System.out.println(list);
    
}
```

the output to print the list is random, every time I execute this code

i-e

> [null, item 1, item 4, item 5, item 6, item 7, item 8, item 9]
>
> [item 1, null, item 2, item 4, item 5, item 3, item 6, item 7, item 8, item 9]
>
> [item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item 5, item 6, item 7, item 8, item 9]

in 1st and 2nd output, there are null items, 1st in 1st output and 2nd in 2nd one respectively. and also size of list is not same.

As per my understanding, the items would be not placed in order in multi-threading. I didn't knew about the items would be null or skipped sometimes while adding in array

I want to understand this behavior, why null items are added to the array and why items are skipped when my method is not **Synchronized**

your valuable answer would help me a lot,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `List.add(Object)` function is not atomic. That is if multiple thread try to add an element to the same list, they may interfere with each other and break the inner workings of the add function (resizing of the internal data structure, computation of the items positions in the list, ...). This may lead to unexpected output or even serious issues (e.g. when using a `HashMap` accross threads without properly synchronizing - even for readonly operations).

If you use a synchronzied `List`:

```
 static List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

This will make method calls on the `list` instance `synchronized` making add an effectively atomic operation. With this change the items will still not be added in order but at least it is ensured that all items will be added properly.

Answer (score 3):

Because adding an item is not an atomic operation, it requires multiple operations, e.g. incrementing the size and assigning the value to an array position.

With multi-threaded race conditions, sometimes two threads may increment at the same time, so it only increments once, not twice, hence final size is less than 10.

Sometimes two threads will both increment in order before assigning value, so a position is skipped and both threads assign to same position, one thread overriding the value of the other, hence a null value and a missing value.

In short, multi-threaded use of an object, like an `ArrayList`, will **corrupt** the list. Don't ever do it. Why you see the result you do doesn't really matter, just don't do it.